# Connecting to softlayer object storage using apache libcloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, python-3.6, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage, libcloud

**Problem:**

Trying to connect to Softlayer Swift Object Storage using apache libcloud and I can't get it to work. I have tried passing in different options to the provider but no matter what I pass in I get the same error. I would appreciate any and all pointers to help me resolve this issue.

**Code:**

```
from pprint import pprint
from libcloud.storage.types import Provider
from libcloud.storage.providers import get_driver

_swift = get_driver(Provider.OPENSTACK_SWIFT)
_authurl = "https://lon02.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0"
_user = "IBMOS<redacted>"
_key = "redacted"

driver = _swift(_user, _key,
                region='lon02',
                ex_force_auth_url=_authurl,
                ex_force_auth_version='1.0',
                ex_force_service_type='object-store',
                ex_force_service_name='cloudFiles')


#pprint(driver.__dict__)
pprint(driver.list_containers())
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 441, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1806, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1539, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise SysCallError(-1, "Unexpected EOF")
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (-1, 'Unexpected EOF')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 448, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='lon02.objectstorage.softlayer.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /auth/v1.0 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "swift.py", line 19, in <module>
    pprint(driver.list_containers())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libcloud/storage/base.py", line 209, in list_containers
    return list(self.iterate_containers())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libcloud/storage/drivers/cloudfiles.py", line 275, in iterate_containers
    response = self.connection.request('')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libcloud/storage/drivers/cloudfiles.py", line 165, in request
    raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libcloud/common/openstack.py", line 223, in request
    raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 536, in request
    action = self.morph_action_hook(action)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libcloud/common/openstack.py", line 290, in morph_action_hook
    self._populate_hosts_and_request_paths()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libcloud/common/openstack.py", line 324, in _populate_hosts_and_request_paths
    osa = osa.authenticate(**kwargs)  # may throw InvalidCreds
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libcloud/common/openstack_identity.py", line 761, in authenticate
    resp = self.request('/v1.0', headers=headers, method='GET')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 603, in request
    headers=headers, stream=stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libcloud/http.py", line 213, in request
    verify=self.verification
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='lon02.objectstorage.softlayer.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /auth/v1.0 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",),))
```

Comment: ¿Have you tried using the library softlayer-object-storage-python instead?, it 
 can be found here: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-python

Comment: Yes I have however I'm not looking into that package I'm looking into apache libcloud. The reason is Softlayer has support for both Swift and S3(https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSG7_7.1.5/srv.common/r_techchg_srv_cloud_S3_715.html) cloud storage and I want to use a package that has support for both when it comes to migrating from one offering to the other. Not to mention I also want python3 support which is there for apache libcloud and not for the package you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the specific issue seen above was due to the system I was using. Once I switched to another system it proceeded even further however there is a bug I identified and filed in apache libcloud with a documented workaround inside the jira ticket here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LIBCLOUD-972.